# Gitlab-ci stage image not pulled

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm facing an strange behaviour.

Below my **.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
image: node:latest

stages:
  - release

release:
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli
  stage: release
  script:
   - release-cli create --name release-branch-$CI_JOB_ID --description "desc" --tag-name job-$CI_JOB_ID --ref $CI_COMMIT_SHA
```

The pipeline is finishing with the following error:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 14.6.0 (5316d4ac)
  on shell-runner gmyChsa1
Preparing the "shell" executor
Using Shell executor...
Preparing environment
Running on myserver.com...
Getting source from Git repository
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/gitlab-runner/builds/gmyChsa1/0/kleyson-sr/changelog-test/.git/
Checking out 21ab4cac as main...
Removing desc.md
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
$ release-cli create --name release-branch-$CI_JOB_ID --description "desc" --tag-name job-$CI_JOB_ID --ref $CI_COMMIT_SHA
bash: line 137: release-cli: command not found
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

The stage release is not pulling and using the **release-cli** image instead of the global **node:latest** image.

How can I fix that ?

PS.: Running the pipeline in a local gitlab server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Running with gitlab-runner 14.6.0 (5316d4ac)
> on shell-runner gmyChsa1

Your job is using a GitLab runner configured with the `shell` executor. This means that the `image:` directive is ignored entirely.

To use an `image:` you will need to use a runner configured with a docker/kubernetes/custom executor that supports running jobs in an image.